# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has been registered.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Was using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions v2.2.0. This nuget package is a transitive dependency for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel. Upgraded Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting v2.2.7. There is no UseKestrel showing up in intellisense. So, commented it out. At run time see the exception - System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer' has been registered.' at host.RunAsync(cancellationToken.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

```
IWebHost host;

host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseUrls($"http://{Environment.MachineName}:5000")
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStartupFilter, ApiVersioningStartupFilter>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(SdsContext), context);
    })
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .Build();
host.RunAsync(cancellationToken.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your custom WebHostBuilder setup with `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` or `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.

But there should also be an extension method for `UseKestrel` in ASP.NET Core 2.2, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderkestrelextensions.usekestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You might not have a using for the namespace those extension methods are in, which is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`.