# No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment' has been registered net core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a service with constructor like this

```cs
public FileManager(IServiceProvider services, IServer server)
{
    _server = server;
}
```

Whenever I call the service, I get the error `No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment' has been registered`.
When I remove the `IServer` dependency away, the program works fine. I have researched about this alot read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61539151/system-invalidoperationexception-no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-hos) saw [this also](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7749) on github and so many others but yet the problem seems not to be resolved.
The solution was working perfectly in `net5` before I decided to migrate to `net6.0`

**Edited**
[image]

Comment: Can you post your startup code? (Program.cs or Startup.cs most likely)

Comment: @boylec1986 have a look at it

Comment: Dont paste code as images please

Comment: @Formula12 Are there any calls to `builder.Services` in your Program.cs / Startup.cs ? The picture of source code that you added is insufficient for determining this. Also, "Whenever I call the service" - are you using DI to instantiate the service? Or do you mean to say that you call the service constructor directly?

Answer (score 0):

Must add service to app container in you program.cs before `var app=builder.build();` or in ConfigureServices(), by example add singleton `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileManager,FileManager>();`

See you Configure and ConfigureServices methods(in .Net5 project) and move add services to buider.Services.Add... and app.Use.. respectively.

Comment: the problem is not that the `FileManager` service is not found but when I include the `IServer` dependency on file manager, the error shows up.

Comment: @Formula12 Which full path to you IServer? Using directives is correct from this path.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem today whilst appearing to have solved it about 6 months ago. It may not be the most optimum solution, but this is how I achieved it.

1. I added the following packages to the project (mine was a .NET 6 AWS lambda) .csproj

```html
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
```

2. Add the following where you Configure your Services.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal;
```

```cs
    this.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(new HostingEnvironment { EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") });
```

Feel free to change the packages as you see fit. Hope it helps.